# compact Riemann surface and branched cover

Tags: riemann-surfaces

Show that a compact Riemann surface admits a branched cover of the
sphere with only simple branch points.

I have this problem and it seems to me that the way is to use Riemann Roch theorem, but I do not know how to exactly apply!

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a branch set $D$ of size greater than or equal to the genus. Then by Riemann-Roch, the dimension of the space of meromorphic functions branching on $D$ with at worst simple poles is greater than or equal to $1$.

Comment: Can't these functions still have non-simple branched points? Branched points need not to be poles.